# Задача об упаковке в контейнеры груза у которого есть обьем и вес

Tags: алгоритм

Нужно упаковать в минимальное кол-во контейнеров (ограниченного размера и грузоподъемности) весь груз(у которого есть размеры и вес). 
Какой алгоритм стоит использовать для решения данной задачи(полный перебор нежелателен)? Или же какую эвристику стоит использовать в любом из существующих эвристических алгоритмов?

Comment: Спасибо, исправила.

Comment: Тогда это не менее классическая задача трёхмерной упаковки (трёхмерный рюкзак).

Comment: Не совсем ясно как в этой задаче учесть вес. Можно, конечно, использовать стандартные алгоритмы и попросту игнорировать слишком большие по весу грузы, но это не кажется оптимальным.

Comment: Любая задача о рюкзаке использует весовые коэффициенты. Мне кажется, что вы путаете её с задачами раскроя.